# Flow issues in flexbox item container

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

I have a flexbox page layout. It consists of a left and right hand sidebar of fixed width, and a central content panel that stretches to fit the remaining page space.

The problem I have is that content inside this central panel is increasing it's container's size to accommodate it. The result I actually want is for any content inside that panel to never be any larger than 100% of the central container width without ever effecting its size. How can I achieve this?

I tried applying a max-width: 100% to the section elements but that didn't work.

Comment: It would be better if you can create a demo of the code that you are using. Image is not of much help unfortunately.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you add an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `padding` on `central panel` and on `sections` you set left and right margin to `auto`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/309/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="left">
     flex-left
  </div>

  <div class="center">
   <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum dignissimos, ullam explicabo incidunt adipisci, quos sunt at repellendus iure, modi asperiores dicta error ut non repellat nulla. Odio, labore, minus.</section>

       <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum dignissimos, ullam explicabo incidunt adipisci, quos sunt at repellendus iure, modi asperiores dicta error ut non repellat nulla. Odio, labore, minus.</section>

       <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum dignissimos, ullam explicabo incidunt adipisci, quos sunt at repellendus iure, modi asperiores dicta error ut non repellat nulla. Odio, labore, minus.</section>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    flex-right
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 1 320px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 1 320px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.center {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Actually, just noticed this has the same problem. If there's a line of text with no spaces longer than the available space it does still resize the parent .center div.

Comment: In what real world scenario you have `line of text with no spaces` :)

Comment: Ok but lets say you do, you can use `word-break:break-all;` and do this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/319/

Answer (score 0):

By default any element placed into a flex container has its `flex-basis` property set to `auto`, this means that if it has no explicitly set width it will just grow to accommodate its content. The solution is simply to set either its `width` property or its `flex-basis` property.

This [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is really helpful for getting your head around how flex works.

Here is a quick [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXJqZV?editors=110).

```
main {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

main > div {
  padding: 15px;
}

main > .center {
  flex-basis: 60%; /*This stops it from getting wider for its content*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-self: stretch;
}

main > .side {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}
```